# how to implement multilevel checkboxes in angularjs without using directives and plugins?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, typescript

I tried lot in different ways. I am not able to implement it. I have JSON response with tree level. I binded all the response with ng-repeat and using ul,li etc.. So when i clicked on parent it should select all(child,subchild) and need to send response to JS on button click(method call). Please help me. Greatly appreciated.

Note : Please help me without jquery.

Comment: Here is a similar question relating to checkboxes in angular.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27734341/angular-checkboxes-in-tree-view/27734733#27734733

Comment: Thanks for swing response. Yes exactly my requirement is similar to that but when i click on Women it should select all. That scenario is not working there.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tries so far and what not working? A fiddle or plunker would be best

Comment: Hello AlexD. As shakinfree said requirement is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27734341/angular-checkboxes-in-tree-view/27734733#27734733